# Using axios with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I want to get data from an API and put them into my `documents`, and I know how to do that, but I don't know the right way. I've seen in some tutorials saying that we have to do every API calls in middlewares, but I can't find any example.

> My code:

listReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  documents: []
}

export default function documents(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_DOCS':
      //set documents = response from api
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

listAction.js

```
export function loadDocs(offset, range) {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_DOCS',
    offset,
    range
  }
}
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

import reducers from './reducers'
const store = createStore(reducers)

export default store
```

Comment: I think by middleware they mean using something like `redux-thunk`, redux sagas or redux-observables to allow you to dispatch "asynchronous" actions.

Comment: Now i understand, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can create a thunk using a redux middleware "Redux-thunk".
thunk is basically a function in which you can make an API call and after getting the data from the server you can dispatch an action to set the data into the reducer.
You Get the dispatch function in the thunk u will create.

So instead of call the dispatch directly you will call the thunk function